martingale convergence for uniformly integrable process
Let $(X_n)_n$ be a martingale that is uniformly integrable (u.i.). I have shown already, that uniform integrability implies boundedness in $L^1$, thus $X_n$ converges almost surely to an integrable r.v. $X_\infty$. Now in the proof, the author defines $Y_n:=|X_n-X_\infty|$, and claims this is obviously u.i., too.
I would have to show, that $\sup_{n\geq0}\mathbb E[Y_n\mathbf 1_{Y_n>M}]$ goes to zero, as $M$ approaches infinity. I have used triangle inequality, to show
$$\sup_{n\geq0}\mathbb E[Y_n\mathbf 1_{\{Y_n>M\}}]\leq\sup_{n\geq 0}\mathbb E[|X_n|\mathbf 1_{\{Y_n>M\}}]+\sup_{n\geq0}\mathbb E[|X_\infty|\mathbf 1_{\{Y_n>M\}}].$$
The first summand should go to zero, as $M$ approaches infinity, as $X_n$ is u.i. But i am not quite sure how to treat the second summand. I am surely overthinking this, but i do not see, how the u.i. of $Y_n$ can be proven formally.

It can be seen by using the fact that a sequence $\left(Y_n\right)$ is
uniformly integrable if and only if $\sup_{n\geqslant 1 }\mathbb E\left[\lvert Y_n\rvert\right]$ is finite and for each positive $\varepsilon$, there exists $\delta$ such that if $A$ is a set for which $\mathbb P(A)<\delta$, then $\sup_{n\geqslant 1}\mathbb E\left[\lvert Y_n\rvert\mathbf{1}_A\right]<\varepsilon$.

Alternatively, if we want to stick to the original definition, use that
\begin{align}
\lvert X+Y\rvert\mathbf{1}_{\lvert X+Y\rvert>R}&\leqslant 
\lvert X\rvert\mathbf{1}_{\lvert X+Y\rvert>R}+\lvert Y\rvert\mathbf{1}_{\lvert X+Y\rvert>R}\\
&=\lvert X\rvert\mathbf{1}_{\lvert X+Y\rvert>R}\mathbf{1}_{\lvert X\rvert\leqslant R/2}+\lvert X\rvert\mathbf{1}_{\lvert X+Y\rvert>R}\mathbf{1}_{\lvert X\rvert> R/2}+\lvert Y\rvert\mathbf{1}_{\lvert X+Y\rvert>R}\mathbf{1}_{\lvert Y\rvert\leqslant R/2}+\lvert Y\rvert\mathbf{1}_{\lvert X+Y\rvert>R}\mathbf{1}_{\lvert Y\rvert> R/2}\\
&\leqslant \lvert X\rvert\mathbf{1}_{\lvert X\rvert\leqslant R/2<\lvert Y\rvert}+\lvert X\rvert \mathbf{1}_{\lvert X\rvert> R/2}+\lvert Y\rvert\mathbf{1}_{\lvert Y\rvert\leqslant R/2<\lvert X\rvert}+\lvert Y\rvert \mathbf{1}_{\lvert Y\rvert> R/2}\\
&\leqslant 2\lvert X\rvert \mathbf{1}_{\lvert X\rvert> R/2}+2\lvert Y\rvert \mathbf{1}_{\lvert Y\rvert> R/2}  ,
\end{align}
where we used $\lvert X\rvert\mathbf{1}_{\lvert X\rvert\leqslant R/2<\lvert Y\rvert}\leqslant \lvert Y\rvert\mathbf{1}_{\lvert X\rvert\leqslant R/2<\lvert Y\rvert}\leqslant  \lvert Y\rvert\mathbf{1}_{ R/2<\lvert Y\rvert}$.
